# How can I override event property setters like for event.pageX?

Tags: javascript

I want to override event.pageX and event.pageY for all events because IE10+ come with a bug that sometimes returns floating point positions for pageX/Y instead of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you can't override this native property. You can build your own getter:

```
MouseEvent.prototype.getPageX = function() {
    return Math.ceil(this.pageX);
}
```

and then use `event.getPageX()` instead of `event.PageX`

**EDIT:**
There is a small experiment as a proof that it is not possible. I made this small event listener, so when I click anywhere, then I can see inspect instance of event:

```
var bod = document.querySelector("body");

bod.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Then I tried to change `MouseEvent` constructor.

```
var M = MouseEvent;
MouseEvent = function() {
    M.apply(this, arguments); // in fact this is not possible
    this.pageX = Math.ceil(this.pageX+15000);
}
```

Now, when you click on screen, what browser does? It makes a new instance of MouseEvent. But it doesn't make it in javascript. It does it in whatever language it wants. So anything like `new MouseEvent` will not happen in js and there is no place where you could override properties of that new object.

As a proof, you can try to create new event on your own with:

```
var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    canBubble: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window,
  });
```

it will actually fail:

```
M.apply(this, arguments);
// TypeError: Failed to construct 'MouseEvent': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

but my point is, that simple click on screen didn't fail, because it doesn't use `new MouseEvent` in js and therefore it can't be overridden.

Comment: Thanks, I do want to centrally override the original setter/getter though so I don't have to think about and change all the possible places where it is used or might be used in the future..

Comment: Thanks for your EDIT, too bad it doesn't work, but at least I can stop looking